# Border lines between labels tcl tk

Tags: user-interface, tcl, border, tk-toolkit

I have a GUI that has a few check buttons and information about the check buttons displayed beside it. The information comes from an array of lists. Each element in the array has multiple categories of information associated with it. I want to place this information in an easy to view GUI. Currently the GUI has the code below. The buttons have no functionality right now, that will come later but what I want to figure out is how to add border lines between each category, basically make the whole thing look more like a table:

```
set tics(ticket1) [list "status1" "ec1"]
set tics(ticket2) [list "status2" "ec2"]
set tics(ticket3) [list "status3" "ec3"]
set cv [canvas .cs  -yscrollcommand [list .sy set]]
set intro [frame $cv.intro]
set lab [label $intro.lab -text "Please click block"]
wm title . "Warning!"
set frame [frame $cv.frame ]
set l1 [label $frame.l1 -text "Block"  -padx $padding]
set l2 [label $frame.l2 -text "Status"  -padx $padding]
set l3 [label $frame.l3 -text "Effort Category" -padx $padding]
set sy [scrollbar .sy -orient v -command [list $cv yview]] 
    pack $cv -expand 1 -fill both -side left 
pack $intro $lab
pack $sy -side right -fill y
grid $l1 -row 0 -column 0 -ipadx $padding -sticky $stickiness 
grid $l2 -row 0 -column 1 -ipadx $padding -sticky $stickiness 
grid $l3 -row 0 -column 2 -ipadx $padding -sticky $stickiness 

set row 1
foreach tic [array names tics] {
        set a [checkbutton $frame.f$tic -text $tic]
    set c 0
    foreach element $tics($tic) {
        set t$c [label $frame.l$tic$c -text $element -padx $padding]
        set c [expr $c+1]
    }   
    grid $a -row $row -column 0 -ipadx $padding -sticky $stickiness
    grid $t0 -row $row -column 1 -ipadx $padding -sticky $stickiness
    grid $t1 -row $row -column 2 -ipadx $padding -sticky $stickiness

    set row [expr $row+1]
}
pack $frame
```

Comment: Could you perhaps, provide a visual of how you would like these "border lines" would look?

Comment: You should consider using `incr row` to increase the value of `row` by one…

Answer (score 0):

For the full table effect, **use the [tktable extension package](http://tktable.sourceforge.net/)**. It's designed for it.

Alternatively, you can create separator widgets with `ttk::separator`; they do nothing except draw themselves as a line, either horizontal or vertical (according to how you configure them). Try doing something like this:

```
button .b1 -text "This is b1"
button .b2 -text "This is b2"
button .b3 -text "This is b3"
button .b4 -text "This is b4"
ttk::separator .s1
ttk::separator .s2

# Basic grid, in pattern style
grid .b1 .s1 .b2
grid .s2  -   -    -sticky ew
grid .b3  x  .b4
# Note that we're *forcing* separator widgets to overlap!
grid configure .s1 -rowspan 3 -sticky ns
```

Whether this looks OK will depend on the visual style you're using. You can change the colour of rows by putting a frame underneath each of the rows that you want to change (you'll probably have to `lower` it, and you'll have to force exactly which cells it occupies).

Stacking widgets can lead to some *really* awesome effects, but it's significantly trickier to get right. If you really want a table, I recommend just using tktable as that actually has a tabular model as opposed to something hacked together.